# Simultaneous Equation (I think)

Tags: elementary-functions

I am not sure whether I am just not remembering the technique or I don't have enough clues to solve this one:

$T_1 - T_2 = 362$

$\frac{T_1}{T_2} = 5.48$

I cannot seem to solve for $T_1$ or $T_2$

I can get as far as substituting one equation into the other:

$T_2 = T_1 - 362 (1)$

$\frac{T_1}{5.48} = T_2 (2)$

(1) into (2)

$\frac{T_1}{5.48} = T_1-362$

$T_1-\frac{T_1}{5.48} = 362$

But can't get any further.

Hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance.

Jon.

Comment: $T_1=5.48T_2$, so $T_1-T_2=4.48T_2$. This is $362$. So $T_2=\frac{362}{4.48}$. Your way will work too, slightly more messy.

Comment: you are welcome jonr,you can easily continue from what what you get,imagine two system two unknown,just little arithemtic

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Both make sense...couldn't see the wood for trees. Its been a while since I did this particular type of problem...looks so simple now! Thank you very much both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so we have

$x-x/5.48=362$

$5.48x-x=362*5.48=1983.76$

or we have

$4.48x=1983.76$

from there we get that $x=442.8035714285714$

now   we  know that $x=T_1=442.8$

what is equal $T_2$?

$T_2=T_1-362=442.8-362=80.8$